# Plotting values versus time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm reading a CSV into pandas. This CSV has several columns with data. One of them has dates and a second one has times.
For each date, I have about 300 times.

```
"Date","Time","Cloud Condition","Rain Condition","Brightness Condition","Cloud Value" 
"2018-12-26","15:25:24","Clear","Dry","Very light","-36.9" 
"2018-12-26","15:30:25","Clear","Dry","Very light","-38.6"
```

I'm using the following statement to read this CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv(*filename*, index_col=['Date', 'Time'])
```

I then can plot some data using this statement:

```
plt.figure; df['data1'].plot();
```

And I get the plot.

But the x axis is labeled `'Date.Time'`.
How can I get the "real" date and time on the axis?

Comment: try experimenting with `pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Can you please show us what your data looks like (format). Also you are not really clear on what plot you want. What should you X and Y axis be ?

Comment: Here the beginning of my data : "Date","Time","Cloud Condition","Rain Condition","Brightness Condition","Cloud Value",...
"2018-12-26","15:25:24","Clear","Dry","Very light","-36.9",...
"2018-12-26","15:30:25","Clear","Dry","Very light","-38.6",...

Comment: I'd like to simply plot some values (like the Cloud Value for example) versus time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the parse_dates argument from `pandas.read_csv` to make it an actual `datetime` column instead of 2 columns of `str`s

```
df = pd.read_csv(<file>, parse_dates={"datetime": ['Date', 'Time']}, index_col="datetime")
```